# Reading TIFF Image Metadata

Tags: c#, metadata, tiff

I'm currently writing an application to read a TIFF File and then perform some compression algorithm. I have successfully done that .. But now, I want to read the metadata of the TIFF Image, but can't seem to find the correct way to do that.

What library and function should I use?

Comment: Did you write some code by your own to read TIFF metadata? If you did, maybe you should post it. Which specific metadata are you interested in?

Comment: I'm can't figure out the correct libraries .. All I found are JPEG related

Answer (score 1):

Even if I do not know which metadata you need to read, *maybe* the standard [TiffBitmapDecoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapdecoder(v=vs.110).aspx) class can help you. Take a look to its [Metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapdecoder.metadata(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: I'm getting this error now: Error 1 The type 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Comment: Did you add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'?

Answer (score 0):

From:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7888/A-library-to-simplify-access-to-image-metadata

In .NET Framework, you can store and retrieve metadata by calling the SetPropertyItem and GetPropertyItem methods of the Image class, and you don't have to be concerned with the details of how a particular file format stores that metadata.

Comment: Thank you .. But this library deals with JPEG only .. didn't extract metadata for TIFF

Comment: Umm ok, description said it works with all image formats but I didn't' really test it on my side.